# Dynamic Variables in Postman is not coming properly

Tags: api, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to delete users in bulk with Postman. To achieve this operation I have to pass all the user id in append url which is like this -

**[https://example.com/test/Users/{{id}}](https://example.com/test/Users/%7B%7Bid%7D%7D)**

id value I am taking from csv file. Please find below screenshot for more understanding -

[image: csv file image]

And postman is taking value in different way. I guess due to the size of variable it is not considering last 3 numbers

[image: Postman preview data]

Please help me in this.
Thanks

Comment: Did you save the csv after changing the value?

Comment: At very first time it was copied as correct value only. if you will compare both value you will find that postman have changed 6552 into 7000

Comment: Adding double quote both ends might help you, I guess. It explicitly says value is String not Number, to help parse value correctly.